# MS Access to connect to SQL Server Express

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Ok I have a strange problem that seems to make no logical sense.

I have a SQL Server Express running on ComputerA. On `ComputerA`, I have designed a MS Access database client to access this data.

I have transferred the MS Access file to `ComputerB` (on same network as `ComputerA`) and I am able to type in the `username` and `password` and things connect and I am able to see the data. Also, I am able to access my SQL Server Express via PHP on any computer. (`slsweb.ocmboces.org/loginpage/SQLTEST2.php`)

On `ComputerC` and `ComputerD`, I have the same MS Access file. When I click on my forms it asks me to connect to the server on ComputerA which is `WIN-XXXXX`. I use the same `username` and `password` but it will not connect.

I have tried to configure ODBC data sources but they will not connect to the server. I also have opened almost everything on the firewall on the server computer which is `ComputerA`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you ping Computer A from C & D?  I assume you are in work group, not a network with Active Directory.  Correct?  Are all the computers running the same OS and version level?  Usually you just need tcp/ip and port 1433 open to connect from a computer to the database server.

Comment: Using command ping -a WIN-XXX? I believe that I am in a workgroup. All computers, to my knowledge, are running Windows 7 @CRAFTYDBA

Comment: Open a command prompt.  Can all the computer ping the database?  Can the database ping all the computers?  Basic Network trouble shooting.

Comment: When I ping from ComputerC & ComputerD I get a message that says it cannot find server @CRAFTYDBA

Comment: That is your problem.  Are you pinging by name?  If so, change it to ping by IP, do not need the port.  Do you have DNS running anywhere?  If that works, change the ODBC to use the IP address or create an LMHOSTS file.

Comment: Yes I am pinging by name. You suggest I ping by IP and port?  I do not believe I have DNS running @CRAFTYDBA

Comment: When I ping using IP address, I get "Request Timed out"

Comment: That means there is no connection between the client and the server.  IE - either issues with cabling, router, firewall, etc.  You need to check them all.

Comment: Thanks again for all the help. This is my first time setting something like this up so it is a learning experience @CRAFTYDBA

Answer (score 0):

Problem:  Unable to ping by name from client computers to database server.

Solution:  Setup the ODBC connection using the IP address only.  Do not need port number if default (1433) is being used.

You can also look into creating an LMHOSTS files.

See KB article below from Microsoft on how to do this for windows 7.  Basically the file translates the name of the server to an ip, poor mans DNS.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/101927

Here is an article on inbound rules for dynamic SQL Server ports.  Just google adding inbound/outbound firewall rules.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175043.aspx

Comment: WHat do I need to enable on the firewall? @CraftyDBA

Comment: Turn off the firewall, can you ping now?

Comment: Both of my firewalls are off but the pinging is still getting "request timed out" @craftydba